# Codeigniter callback failure

Tags: php, codeigniter, callback

Can anyone see what I'm missing?

I'm using Codeigniter v1.72.

In the doc:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html

It states:

$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'callback_username_check');

```
function username_check($str)
    {
        if ($str == 'test')
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('username_check', 'The %s field can not be the word "test"');
            return FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
```

In my class User extends Controller

I have in function register:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean', 'callback_username_check('.$username.')');

I have also tried 

$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean', 'callback_username_check');
```

And

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean', 'callback_username_check['.$username.']');


    function username_check($str)
    {
            $this->load->model('User_model', '', TRUE);
            $taken = $this->User_model->countUsername($str);

            if($taken)
            {
                $this->form_validation->set_message('username_check', 'That username is already taken');
                return FALSE;
            }
            else
                return TRUE;
    }
```

There are no errors at all, none of my approaches work, the code behaves like it's not there.

Comment: i can't see where you can add a callback to this function.

Comment: @helle: The function IS a callback. If you read the web page he cited, you'll see that `callback_username_check` sets `username_check` as a callback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I'm assuming the rest of your code is correct. It might help to show the whole `User` class.

You might want to check if CodeIgniter lets you invoke callback functions AND prepping/validator functions in the same rule. If it doesn't allow that, you could call `trim`, `require`, and `xss_clean` in your callback function.

I will say, though, that if it is allowed, then this is definitely the **RIGHT** form:

`$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean', 'callback_username_check');`

This is **wrong**:

`$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean', 'callback_username_check['.$username.']');`

And this is **wrong** too:

`$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean', 'callback_username_check('.$username.')');`

See, in that line, you shouldn't actually be *CALLING* the function. Rather, you're passing a string to the `set_rules()` function that it will parse and figure out what function you want to use as a callback.

As the documentation states, whatever the value of `username` is, will be passed as the argument to your callback function.

**EDIT:**

I was going to say try this:

`$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_username_check');`

But I don't think it will work. Instead, this should work:

```
function username_check($str)
    {
        $this->load->model('User_model', '', TRUE);
        $taken = $this->User_model->countUsername($str);

        if($taken)
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('username_check', 'That username is already taken');
            return FALSE;
        }
        else if(!$str) {
            // This is functioning as the required rule
            return FALSE;
        }
        else {
            $str = trim($str);
            $str = $this->input->xss_clean($str);
            return $str;
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!!
This does work:

$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'callback_username_check');

But now I can't call trim, require, and xss_clean.
Any idea how to get this done?